# How to run phpvirtualbox on MacOS?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to run the phpvirtualbox software on macos. These are the steps I followed.

1. Installed Apache Tomcat and PHP.
2. Downloaded the [phpvirtualbox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/). Extracted to tomcat webapp folder, changed the configuration like mentioned in the [docs](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpvirtualbox/wiki/Home/). (till here it is working fine).  But it is unable to authenticate to the user.

```
VirtualBox web service 5.1.22 r115126 darwin.amd64 (Apr 28 2017 17:26:14) release log
00:00:00.000264 main     Log opened 2017-07-04T23:41:57.561859000Z
00:00:00.000265 main     Build Type: release
00:00:00.000285 main     OS Product: Darwin
00:00:00.000293 main     OS Release: 16.6.0
00:00:00.000301 main     OS Version: Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
00:00:00.000480 main     DMI Product Name: MacBookPro12,1
00:00:00.000561 main     DMI Product Version: 1.0
00:00:00.000595 main     Host RAM: 8192MB (8.0GB) total, 1896MB available
00:00:00.000601 main     Executable: /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/vboxwebsrv
00:00:00.000602 main     Process ID: 6818
00:00:00.000603 main     Package type: DARWIN_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.004779 main     IPC socket path: /tmp/.vbox-air-ipc/ipcd
00:00:00.012153 SQPmp    Socket connection successful: host = default (localhost), port = 18083, master socket = 6
00:00:05.012197 Watchdog Statistics: 0 websessions, 0 references
00:02:42.043693 SQPmp    Request 1 on socket 7 queued for processing (1 items on Q)
00:02:42.043726 SQW01    New SOAP thread started
00:02:42.043744 SQW01    Processing connection from IP=127.0.0.1 socket=7 (0 out of 1 threads idle)
00:02:42.044971 SQW01    External authentication library is 'VBoxAuth'
00:02:42.078267 SQW01    Access for user 'air ' denied
```

Config file for phpvirtualbox view
[image: Config file for phpvirtualbox view]
Error on phpvirtualbox client.
[image: Error]

how to run phpvirtualbox on MacOS, have anyone tried this on MacOS?

Update- I followed installation instructions on Ubuntu, and it worked great. I think in MacOS, its tricky, especially configuring user. It would be helpful if anyone explains in detail how to do in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to install the virtualbox web server. Which should be installed point at the address of your $var location